# In Opera, is it possible to set a flag to enable the Fullscreen API to trigger without an event?

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, opera

In Firefox, it is possible to set a flag in the `about:config` page to enable calls to `element.mozRequestFullScreen();` to work even if the user did not initiate a fullscreen event. The flag in question: `full-screen-api.approval-required;false` Of course, this only applies to browsers I control (which is true in my case). I want to develop a kiosk application, and I want the app to enable full screen mode, and I have selected Opera to be the browser which is used to serve my app.

Is there a similar flag or option that can achieve the same in Opera? Alternately, is it possible to start Opera in full screen mode? Ever since they have switched their engine to webkit, the documentation is out of date and many of the start flags do not work.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: So are you trying to use Opera Presto, or Opera Blink (fork of Webkit)? According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen), 12.1 (Presto) as well as 15+ (Blink) support the fullscreen API ("API for allowing content (like a video or canvas element) to take up the entire screen."), though "Opera 12.1 uses the older specificaton's `:fullscreen-ancestor` pseudo-class instead of the the `::backdrop` pseudo-element.".

Comment: Opera Presto is long dead. I am using Opera 26, which uses Blink as its rendering engine.

Comment: Presto is only dead if you're one of those who considered it dead due to low global market share before Blink came along. I use Opera 12.x for some things, stable channel (Opera 26) for others, and right now I'm typing on 28 (dev channel). Anywho, if you're looking for a flag, have you looked through `opera://flags/` yet? Which documentation is out of date? The help is usually versioned, afaik, and of course Presto start options don't apply to Blink, which is why I asked what you were using. If Blink, why ask specifically about Opera? Why not Chrome (same engine, more users)?